# find the trigger button by ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

how do i find the trigger button in ***form*** by ***ng-submit***
and get attribut in this button

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="submit" att1="A" att2="B" value="Edit" />
  <input type="submit" att1="C" att2="D" value="Delete" />
</form>

<script>
  function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert(this.att1)
      alert(this.att2)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For me this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs

Comment: For me it's not, totally different issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use ng-click to change values on your scope prior to submission

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="setAtts('A', 'B')" value="Edit" />
  <input type="submit" ng-click="setAtts('C', 'D')" value="Delete" />
</form>

<script>
  function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert($scope.att1);
      alert($scope.att2);
    };

    $scope.setAtts = function(a1, a2) {
      $scope.att1 = a1;
      $scope.att2 = a2;
    };
  }
</script>
```

Edit: As a side note `$event` will not work for ng-submit, if you're interested in using `$event.target` (which probably shouldn't be done from a controller anyhow)