# Angularjs ng-click: how to get `this` data?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onclick, jquery-1.9

Let say I have this item in the list with angular `ng-click` event.

```
<a data-id='102' ng-click='delete()'>Delete</a>
```

How can I get the data/ info if `this` then?

```
        $scope.delete = function() {

             var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
             console.log(id); // I want to get 102 as the result
             if (confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
                $('#contactsGrid tr[data-id="' + id + '"]').hide('slow');

            }
         };
```

Comment: Don't know why this got downvotes. It's a valid question for someone new to the AngularJS approach, and it's expected that someone new to AngularJS would be looking to StackOverflow for guidance.

Comment: @ChristopherParker +1 not to mention that it's a really well written question compared to many...!

Comment: I have to same question. I am new to AngularJS and JQuery and interaction between them is not so easy to understand.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The right solution will be is to pass the id as an parameter to the delete function like

```
<a data-id='102' ng-click='delete(102)'>Delete</a>
```

then

```
    $scope.delete = function(id) {
         console.log(id); // I want to get 102 as the result
         if (confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
            $('#contactsGrid tr[data-id="' + id + '"]').hide('slow');

        }
     };
```

---

**This should not be done**, but just to demonstrate

Inside `ng-click` you can get the event using `$event`, so

```
<a data-id='102' ng-click='delete($event)'>Delete</a>
```

then

```
$scope.delete = function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).data('id');
    console.log(id); // I want to get 102 as the result
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dgu32/)

Comment: Yep, best to think about `delete()` independently of how its called. Happens to be from a click, but in the general case it wouldn't. Note though: presumably this <a> tag is inside of some kind of ng-repeat? If so, the iterated item is in scope and would be accessible via `this`.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this answer.
But why not to use the $event ?

Comment: bump. also curious as to why not use $event?

Comment: @youri sorry, what about `$event`? and how do you suggest to use it

Comment: I'm using your solution. that works fine for me. however i am curious why you write "This should not be done, but just to demonstrate.". I'm curious why one should not use the $event solution.

Comment: This should not be done because of the AngularJS concept if we believe this post : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs)

Comment: Nice answer this is resole to my problum thank @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 4):

To access clicked link tag attributes

In **jQuery**,

```
<a class='test' data-id='102' ng-click='delete(102)'>Delete</a>
```

on click of above link is handled as

```
$('.test').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-id')); 
});
```

Demo code for jQuery : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0ac3ep0/)

In **Angularjs**,

```
<a class='test' data-id='102' ng-click='delete($event)'>Delete</a>
```

on click of above link is handled as

```
$scope.delete = function (e) {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-id")); 
 }
```

Demo code for Angularjs : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maLjsr2j/)

Comment: Wouldn't you get $ is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the event data for Jquery in angular using:

```
  $scope.myClickedEvent = function(clickEvent) {
    $scope.clickEvent = simpleKeys(clickEvent);
    angular.element(clickEvent.currentTarget);
    console.log(angular.element(clickEvent.currentTarget).text());
   /*
   * return a copy of an object with only non-object keys
   * we need this to avoid circular references
   */
   function simpleKeys (original) {
    return Object.keys(original).reduce(function (obj, key) {
      obj[key] = typeof original[key] === 'object' ? '{ ... }' : original[key];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  }
};
```

Your clicked element should contain an ng-click like this

```
ng-click="myClickedEvent($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some other reason, you still need to access the element here's how I did it :

```
<span ng-click="selectText($event)"></span>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.selectText = function(event) {
  var element = event.currentTarget; // returns the span DOM Element
  // Now you can access its dataset just like in plain old JS
  // In my case it was for selecting the content of a tag on click anywhere on the tag
};
```