# Event with reference dom in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have multiple dom like

`<custom>sample text1</custom>
<custom>sample text2</custom>`

And they will compile with transclude to

`<custom><p ng-click='clickMe()'>sample text1</p></custom>
<custom><p ng-click='clickMe()'>sample text2</p></custom>`

```
directive('custom', function() {
    return {
        //...
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.clickMe = (function (elem) {
                console.log(elem.text());
                // log "sampla text1" and "sample text2"
                return function () {
                    console.log(elem.text());
                    // Always log "sample text2" on click
                }
            })(element);
        }
    }
});
```

So... how can I select clicked DOM in scope function?

The $event isnt good answer, because of dynamic parent with p tag.

Thanks for your reading :)

Comment: Why do you not write your own directive, and use $element.bind('click',function(e) ... in the link?

Comment: use element bind still cannot grab element

Comment: unless iterate parent checking

Comment: Have a look at the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs

Comment: because of event bubbling, event.target cannot select directive directly

Comment: And the custom tag are dynamic amount, not created with ng-repeat. I wanna display it directly by back-end server.

Comment: Find the problem! because of unisolated scope in these directve. Thanks for all :)