# AngularJS: Using ng-repeat on <li></li> with different function calls for ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a menu.  There will be varying numbers of items in the menu, but each item will call a different function when they are selected.  I feel it would be cleaner to use ng-repeat to display all the items based on a template, but I can't figure out how to call different functions from the template.  In C++ you can pass a pointer to a function as a variable to a function, but my searches to find something similar in JavaScript/AngularJS are not providing me with anything useful.  Before I go and code each button individually, and copy/paste my template, is there a way that I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative 1:

JS:

```
$scope.items =
[
  { name: 'item 1', action: 'function1' },
  { name: 'item 2', action: 'function2' },
  { name: 'item 3', action: 'function3' }
];

$scope.execute = function(action) {
  $scope[action]();
};

$scope.function1 = function () {
 console.log('function1');
);

$scope.function2 = function () {
  console.log('function2');
};

$scope.function3 = function () {
  console.log('function3');
};
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="execute(item.action)">
  {{ item.name }}
</li>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/T6Q3btvk3qbi2SgpIGb6?p=preview

Alternative 2:

JS:

```
$scope.items =
[
  { name: 'item 1', action: function () { console.log('function 1');} },
  { name: 'item 2', action: function () { console.log('function 2');} },
  { name: 'item 3', action: function () { console.log('function 3');} }
];

$scope.executor = function(item) {
  item.action();
};
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="executor(item)">
  {{ item.name }}
</li>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tDuhc2cZgVJ2mQUQm0eq?p=preview

Comment: Very comprehensive overview, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="click(item)">Text</li>
</ul>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.click = function (item) {
    item.handler();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question, this might solve your problem. [Accessing clicked element in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs)
You don't want to call a different function on each link, instead pass the link element.