# overzealous filter on nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a series of `ng-repeat`ed ul/li sets, and I want to make one set of li's visible when a link at the ul level is clicked.

My code is based around the answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431211 which suggests that model mutation is the right way to do this.

The filter seems to be more zealous than anticipated, and I end up with nothing.

How can I achieve this functionality?

```
div ng-controller="DeviceController">
    <ul ng-repeat="category in devices">
        <a ng-click="setCategory(category)">{{category.name}}</a>
        <li ng-repeat="device in selected.devices | filter: isSelected(category)">
            <a href="device?id={{device.ID}}">{{device.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

function DeviceController($scope) {
    $scope.devices = [
        {name: 'Desktop',
         devices: [{id:1, name:'Olivia'},
                   {id:2, name:'Cayenne'}]
        },
        {name: 'Laptop',
         devices: [{id:3, name:'Probook'},
                   {id:4, name:'Asus G750'}]
        },
        {name: 'Tablet',
         devices: [{id:5, name:'Transformer Prime'},
                   {id:4, name:'Galaxy Note 10.1'}]
        }
    ];

    $scope.setCategory = function(category) {
        $scope.selected = category
    }

    $scope.isSelected = function(category) {
        return $scope.selected === category;
    }
}
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3rV6w/6/

I can't figure out why that isSelected() function works well as a condition on the active class (in the referenced answer) but doesn't perform equally as a filter. Scope perhaps? various console.log's suggest that it should work, but..

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up discarding the filter, and using ng-hide instead.

```
<ul ng-repeat="category in devices">
    <a ng-click="setCategory(category)">{{category.name}}</a>
    <li ng-repeat="device in selected.devices" ng-hide="!isSelected(category)">
        <a href="device?id={{device.ID}}">{{device.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I think was happening is that the ng-filter was comparing 'device' with the true/false returned by isSelected(category). This will never match, so no results made it past the filter.