# jQuery inside ng-click to pass html element reference

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**NOTE:** Not a duplicate of above. Above is accessing clicked element, this question is about accessing a different element.

**QUESTION**

How can I pass an element (not the clicked element) from my html document to an Angular scope method in an `ng-click`?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8Zs/2/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type='text'></input>
    <button ng-click="clickHandler($('input'));">One</button>
    <button onclick="alert(typeof $('input'));">Two</button>
  </div>  
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickHandler = function(el) {
        alert(typeof el);
        // real code work with element---set focus
    }
});
```

In this example when you click the second button, which uses `onclick` you get "object". When you click on the first button which passes through `ng-click` you get "undefined".

I'm trying to avoid moving the jQuery code itself into the controller or into Angular in general to maintain testability.

**EDIT:**

My original example used jQuery to find the first `<button>` element which is easily handled by `$event`. This is not actually indicative of the problem I want to solve and was my mistake in translating my actual problem to a simple reproducible.

The linked duplicates are not the same problem.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selectors are not valid angular expressions, but its clear to me what you're trying to do.

The only way I can think of to do this is to assign the input element on scope:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type='text'></input>
    <button ng-click="clickHandler(input);">One</button>
    <button onclick="alert(typeof $('input'));">Two</button>
  </div>  
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.input = $('input', $element);

    $scope.clickHandler = function(el) {
        alert(typeof el);
    }
});
```

[Demo FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D5hcp/)

**[EDIT]**

**Better Alternative**

I am not sure why one would want to pass a view element to a click handler. Perhaps there is a better way - e.g.; pass the model that the input element is bound to instead.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type='text' ng-model="name"></input>
    <button ng-click="clickHandler(name);">One</button>
  </div>  
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $element) {
    $scope.name = 'John';

    $scope.clickHandler = function(model) {
        if (model == 'Tim') {
            alert("No!!! You're John!");
            $scope.name = 'John';
        }
    }
});
```

By passing the model, and manipulating the model that's bound to the input, the view (input element) is updated automatically.  That is more angular, and less jquery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note that in my example I was not actually accessing the clicked element, which mean `$event` will not work in my scenario. I've updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Again I think my example is too simple. That I really want to do in the controller is focus the element, hence the need for a reference to the element itself.