# Toggle class of parent element using ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some javascript that I'm trying to convert into Angular:

```
$('.col-lg .fa-clock-o').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('set-time');
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

I've tried adding the following to the child element containing the link, but it doesn't work, maybe theres a proper 'angular' way to do this instead?

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$(this).parent().toggleClass('set-time')"></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery inside ng-click to pass html element reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592158/jquery-inside-ng-click-to-pass-html-element-reference)

Comment: Are you using angularjs or angular 2/4? Because in angular there is no ng-click, you would use (click)="foo()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more 'Angular' way to do this would be to set a variable which represents whether or not the `set-time` class is present on the parent element. By default this would be `undefined` which is falsy.

Then to toggle it in your ng-click you can just set the value to be the opposite of what it currently is.

```
<div ng-class="{'set-time': setTimeClass}">
    <a href class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="setTimeClass = !setTimeClass">toggle class</a>
</div>
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```css
.set-time {
 background :red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-class="{'set-time': setTimeClass}">
        <a href class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="setTimeClass = !setTimeClass">toggle class</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. If I have multiple divs inside a ng-repeat, is it possible to extend your approach to toggle the class of the parent element, and also set the class of all the *other* parent div elements to false?

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but not sure its the angular way:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleTimepickerPopup($event)"></a>
```

Controller:

```
public toggleTimepickerPopup(event : any) : void{
    jquery(event.target).parent().toggleClass('set-time');
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent is not a function, it's a prototype:

Correct usage is:
`$(this).parent`

And your anchor element:

`<a href="#" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$(this).parent.toggleClass('set-time')"></a>`