# Convert jquery function to angular?

Tags: angularjs, less

HTML:

```
<div class="day-row" ng-repeat="(a, b) in $ctrl.myModel">
     <div class="col-lg">
         <a href="#" class="my-btn" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleTimepickerPopup($event)"></a>
         <div class="the-container">
```

LESS:

```
         &.set-time {
            .timepicker-container {
              display: block;
            }
          }
```

JavaScript:

```
jquery(".my-btn").each(function () {
        if (jquery(this).is(jquery(event.target))) {
            jquery(this).parent().toggleClass('set-time');
        } else {
            jquery(this).parent().removeClass('set-time');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
```

This jquery function toggles the class for the link that
was clicked on, and removes the class for all other links in the ng-repeat.

I'd like to convert this to angular if possible. I had a similar question [Toggle class of parent element using ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309314/toggle-class-of-parent-element-using-ng-click) where the selected answer worked, but now I need to extend it to not only toggle the class of the parent element, but to remove the class from the parents of all the sibling elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `b` is your object, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="day-row" 
     ng-repeat="(a, b) in $ctrl.myModel">
     <div class="col-lg"
          ng-class="{ 'set-time': $ctrl.selected === b }">
         <a href="#" class="my-btn" aria-hidden="true" 
            ng-click="$ctrl.selected = b"></a>
```

This will toggle the class `set-time` on your div when the anchor is clicked and removes the class on all other elements.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for the second part of my question - removing the class from all *other* parent elements of the anchor elements in the ng-repeat