# How to get element clicked with angular js ngClick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to add a class to a element when clicked with angularjs (the element is generated via ngRepeat). I needed to know the element clicked by ng-click="foo()".

Code goes like this (but I leave the controller and app call out):

```js
function campaign_list_controller($http) {
  this.open_options = function(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="action_select">
  <div class="option" ng-click="ctrl.open_options()">Actions</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs

Comment: `<div class="option" ng-click="ctrl.open_options(this)">Actions</div>`

Comment: why don't use `ng-class`? instead of playing with a DOM from controller.

Comment: @PankajParkar how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This... it's work perfect for you...

```js
function campaign_list_controller($http) {
  this.open_options = function($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).css("color", "red");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="action_select">
  <div class="option" ng-click="ctrl.open_options($event)">Actions</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this : -

```
<div class="option" ng-click="ctrl.open_options(this)">Actions</div>
```

Comment: How to get the element from the object passed to the function?

Comment: pass var in your function