# Change background color of cell using Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using Angular in my application.

```
 <td ng-click="selectTime(this)" >
```

I have a Table with lots of cells and I want to change background color of the cell when it is selected. I am passing the current element (this) to my function selectTime.

```
$scope.selectTime = function (element) {

        $(element).addClass("active");

    }



.active {
            background-color:orangered;
        }
```

For some reason even if I am adding a class the background color is not changing.

Comment: Orantered not a color will red or orange

Comment: That is not the issue! Even if I put red or orange it does not set any color on the table cell.

Comment: The element is valid to jquery?

Comment: Try to use angular.element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to use `jQuery` to manipulate the DOM inside a controller function.

Use `ng-class`.

```
<td ng-click="selectTime($event)" ng-class="{'orange': event.selected, 'red': !event.selected }"> </td>
```

Remember to pass in `$event` as a parameter to your `ng-click` directive.

Your controller function would look like this

```
$scope.selectTime = function (event) {
     $(event).selected = true;
}
```

Credit should be attributed to this answer

[Accessing clicked element in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs)

Comment: But that will set the class and the color for all the TD element in the Table. I only want to set on the element which was clicked.

Comment: You have to specify the position with the `$index` parameter assuming your td is inside an ng-repeat loop

Comment: I don't think I can use $index since I am not using angular to loop through my elements. I am using ASP.NET MVC server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward vanilla JS approach, though Richard Hamilton's answer is much better in terms of handling this in an Angular way:

```
<td ng-click="select($event)"></td>
```

and the JS:

```
$scope.select = function(event) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');//clear old active cells
    }
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a bin for this.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app',[])
        .controller('tableController', tableController);

    function tableController() { 
   
      var vm = this;
   
      vm.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];    
      
      vm.changebgColor = changebgColor;

      function changebgColor(item){
    
    vm.selectedIndex = item;
      
    }
   
  }
  
})();
```

```css
table tr td{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}

.red{
 background-color:red;
}

.blue{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="tableController as vm">
  
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
      <td 
     data-ng-class="{ 'red': $index == vm.selectedIndex }"
     data-ng-click="vm.changebgColor($index)">{{item}}
   </td>
    </tr>    
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps you.