# Get Element Containing Click Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to use event deligation to determine which template will be used in my directive. The problem is I cannot figure out how to get the button element where the click event is bound. The event target can vary depending on where the mouse is when the user clicks. It can be either the span or the button tag. What is the best way to get the button element whether the target is the span or button without all kinds of crazy conditional code?

Also I cannot customize the directive because I am using Angular Material and I can't use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="main.authDialog($event)">
  <span class="ng-scope">Sign Up</span>
  <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: A *runnable* [MCVE] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) makes it easier for you to get useful answers.

Comment: **[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12431211/3639582)** might help. You can access the element by `$event.target` in `authDialog()` definition.

Comment: why not attached eventlisteners using a short for loop to all elements you are interested and whenever an element is click the handler will return the target?.Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: @ShaunakD: `$event.target` will be a descendant element (such as the span or div in the button), not the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` tells you the element on which the event was hooked, rather than the one on which it was triggered (`event.target`).

Example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('exModule', []);
myApp.controller('exController', function($scope) {
  $scope.main = {
    authDialog(e) {
      console.log("target", e.target);
      console.log("currentTarget", e.currentTarget);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="exModule" ng-controller="exController">
  <button ng-click="main.authDialog($event)">
    <span class="ng-scope">Sign Up</span>
    <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: That HTML is invalid, [`button` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) cannot contain [`div` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the invalid HTML, that is the way Angular Material does it after transclusion. Guess there is not much to be done there.

Comment: @Aaron: Sounds like a messed up template. I'm quite certain Angular isn't forcing invalid HTML on people.

Comment: So the button directive is as follows:

  <md-button
      class="md-primary md-raised signup"
      ng-click="main.authDialog($event)">Sign Up
  </md-button>

Adding the class md-raised seems to make the directive add the div. I cannot see any way from the documentation to change that:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdButton

Comment: Actually even removing the class the ripple container is still there.

Comment: So that's [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) rather than Angular. I see the divs in their demos, too. That's pretty shocking; it's Just Plain Wrong™. :-) `div`s can only be used where [*flow content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected, but the content model of `button` is [*phrasing content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).