# AngularJS: Accessing the changed class of an element after ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have applied `ng-click` on an element and within the function, I want to access the DOM element itself. I could do that with :

```
var element = $document[1].getElementById('<id of the element>');
```

However, the problem I am facing is that when that element is clicked, it's class changes. But the element I get using the above method is the previous state of the element before the click. How can I get access to the new attributes of an element after the click is performed ?

**Update**

I am using AngularJS' `smart-table` for displaying data fetched from backend. The library offers sort functionality but it sorts the data which is already fetched from the DB and is present in front end. I wanted to tweak it so that when I click the sort button, I should be fetching data from the backend and update the `rowCollection` so that the table refreshes. Now, in order to trigger the API call, I was thinking of using `ng-click` event on table headers. Also, I need to know whether I need to sort in ascending order or descending order. So, for that, `smart-table` automatically appends a class `sort-ascent` or `sort-descent` to the table header when it is clicked. So, I thought maybe if I can access that, then using the combination of the header column (sort key) and the class (sort order), I can hit the backend API and fetch the appropriate data.

I understand the solution looks more of a hack then a proper way of doing things.

Comment: This seems like a very un-Angular way of doing things. Maybe if you described exactly what it is you're attempting to achieve (update your question) we can better help you find a more suitable method.

Comment: instead of sending element id as a parameter how about sending the elements object reference i.e. this ?

Comment: @Lex : updated the description

Comment: As per the documentation of `smart-table`, there was a lot cleaner way of doing this. Basically, I had to override the `stPipe` function to make the API call. That makes this question as "not required"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at this answer : [Accessing clicked element in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs)

You can access by `$event.target`

```
<button ng-click="yourSubmit($event)"></button>
```

Comment: And as Lex says : it's very un-angular. Remember you can use ng-class and play with it.