# Send (this) element on Angular

Tags: angularjs

How can i send clicked element in function with ng-click? I tried like this but it didn't work;

```
<div ng-click="examplef(angular.element(this))">Click</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing clicked element in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430820/accessing-clicked-element-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you :) @Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular Expressions the `this` object is the current scope. However, the `ng-click` directive exposes the event object as `$event`.

```
<div ng-click="examplef($event.target)">Click</div>
```

The clicked element is the `target` property of the event object.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)